# Punctuation before quoted speech after transitive speech verb

Tags: punctuation, reported-speech, quotations, direct-speech

Which is the more correct way to write this:

> "I heard you don't like noodles." He suggested, "you should get the soup."

> "I heard you don't like noodles." He suggested: "You should get the soup."

Or another altogether? (The speaker is the same throughout)

Comment: Is this meant to represent one person saying "I heard you like noodles. You should get the soup"?

Comment: @JamesK yes...........

Comment: ***I*** suggest rephrasing to *"I heard you don't like noodles. You should get the soup," he suggested.* Or in *British* orthography, move the comma to ***after*** the quote-delimited "reported speech".

Answer (score 0):

The first quote doesn't end the sentence, so "He" should not be capitalised.  A comma is sufficient after suggested.  The word "You" should be capitalised.

I question if "suggested" is the right word to use, as "I heard you like noodles" is not a suggestion.

Comment: "I heard you don't like noodles," he said. "I suggest you get the soup." That's one possibility.

Comment: I'm only interested in the second part of my example, the "I heard you don't like noodles" part was just meant to give a little context and show that directly before the introduction of a new speech verb, this speaker had already been talking

Comment: "He suggested" is not meant to be about "I heard you like noodles" at all. It is "you should get the soup" that "he suggested"

Comment: However the quote verb "suggested" is particularly about the part of the quote that comes before it.  Now the fact that the whole utterance is a suggestion makes it possible to use the quote verb "suggested", but you should be aware that there is an issue here.  If you want to use "suggested" put the whole thing in one quote  `"I heard you like noodles. You should get the soup." he suggested.`